# How can you customize embedded QuickTime controls like Apple does?

Tags: javascript, quicktime, movie

I'd like to embed QuickTime movies on my site using custom controls (play/pause/volume) like [Apple does on its website](http://www.apple.com/itunes/). I'm assuming it's just some fancy JavaScript and .gifs/.pngs?

Answer (score 4):

I think they're using the javascript API for Quicktime and attaching functions to individual elements such as play, pause etc.

[Quicktime Javascript API stuff](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502053024/http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html) (on Wayback Machine)

[Apple: About HTML5 Audio and Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using a shoutcast stream & jQuery:

```
<EMBED name="shoutcastPlayer" enablejavascript="true" src="qtlogo.mov"
qtsrc="http://foo.bar:554/listen.pls"
autoplay="false" controller="false" loop="true"
pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/'></EMBED>

<a href="#" onclick="$('[name=shoutcastPlayer]')[0].Play();">Play</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('[name=shoutcastPlayer]')[0].Stop();">Pause</a>
```

As the other poster pointed out, this is all contained within the [QT Javascript API](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html).

Comment: The URL returns a 404. I'm currently looking for the QT JavaScript API and can't find it anywhere. Do you have the current link maybe?